# Using PrintNode to Transfer data to Excel

Tags: rest, http, dymo

I am trying to take data for a USB-HID scale (dymo S100) and print it in Excel. I came across a program called PrintNode: https://www.printnode.com/docs/reading-usb-scales-over-the-internet/

It seems like the solution however I don't have enough knowledge to make use of the API to transfer data to Excel. Any advice would be a tremendous help. Thank you.

Comment: I can't find a lot of resources for printNode and I tried to use the API but i can't quite figure it out. I contacted support but they haven't gotten back to me. Other than this I've tried TWedge which was close but it only accepts USB-HID keyboard not point of sale(Dymo S100). Currently i am trying to build a custom application using C#, .NEt and the HID library but I've never programming C# before so it'll take a while to get my head around it.

Comment: Here is a the API instructions for the scales section in the PrintNode API, if you could point out to me how I can access the data from the scale that'd be a big help, Thank you!
https://www.printnode.com/docs/api/curl/#scales